# Where is 2 dimensional array's size and how to use point to make 1 dimensional to 2?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

Just as the following code:

```
int a[100],b[10][10];
```

We declare two arrays, one is one dimensional array of 100 elements and other is two dimensional array of 10*10.

My question is, **where** is the size of b's line (10) stored?

And, **How** could I use the type like c[][] to visit an element in array a?

At present, I know two ways to do this. The first one is as below

```
#define c[(x)][(y)] a[(x*10)+(y)]
```

The other is use memcpy to copy a two dimensional array.

Is there any other way?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Can you please write a simple code or somthing so that your question could be more clear.:)

Comment: This `#define c[(x)][(y)] a[(x*10)+(y)]` won't get pre-processed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How could I use the type like c[][] to visit a element in a?

```
int (*c)[10];

c = (int (*)[10])a;
```

it will cast **a** to a multidimensional-array

Comment: Thank you very much,you solved the most important problem for me

Answer (score 4):

> where is the size of b's line (10) store?

Do

```
int b[3][5];
size_t rows = sizeof b / sizeof b[0] 
size_t columns = sizeof b[0] / sizeof b[0][0];
```

to get the number of rows and columns, that are `3` and `5`

---

> How could I use the type like c[][] to visit a element in a

```
int a[15];
int (*c)[3][5] = (int (*)[3][5]) &a;

/* Assign a's elements here. */

int a0 = (*c)[0][0];
int a1 = (*c)[0][1];
...
int a4 = (*c)[0][4];
int a5 = (*c)[1][0];
...
int a14 = (*c)[2][4];
```

Your proposal to use a `#define` would work if done properly:

```
#define c(x, y) (a[(x) * 10 + (y)])

int a[15];

/* Assign a's elements here. */

int a0 = c(0, 0);
int a1 = c(0, 1);
...
int a4 = c(0, 4);
int a5 = c(1, 0);
...
int a14 = c(2, 4);
```

Comment: Perhaps my bad English puzzle you,Thank you in any case